# H.264 Decoder not working properly?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, h.264

I've gone over the code for this decoder for elementary h.264 bitstreams a hundred times, tweaking things along the way, with no luck. When I send the output CMSampleBuffers to an AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer, they don't appear, presumably because there's something wrong with how I'm decoding them.

I get no error messages anywhere; the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer has no error and "status" is "1" (aka .rendering), CMSampleBufferIsValid() returns "true" on the outputted CMSampleBuffers, and I encounter no errors in my decoder either.

I'm stumped and my hope is that a more experienced developer can catch something that I'm missing.

I input raw bytes here (typealias FrameData = [UInt8])

```
func interpretRawFrameData(_ frameData: inout FrameData) -> CMSampleBuffer? {
    let size = UInt32(frameData.count)

    var naluType = frameData[4] & 0x1F
    var frame: CMSampleBuffer?

    // The start indices for nested packets. Default to 0.
    var ppsStartIndex = 0
    var frameStartIndex = 0

    switch naluType {
    // SPS
    case 7:
        print("===== NALU type SPS")
        for i in 4..<40 {
            if frameData[i] == 0 && frameData[i+1] == 0 && frameData[i+2] == 0 && frameData[i+3] == 1 {
                ppsStartIndex = i
                spsSize = i - 4 // Does not include the size of the header
                sps = Array(frameData[4..<i])

                // Set naluType to the nested PPS packet's NALU type
                naluType = frameData[i + 4] & 0x1F
                break
            }
        }
        // If nested frame was found, fallthrough
        if ppsStartIndex != 0 { fallthrough }
    // PPS
    case 8:
        print("===== NALU type PPS")
        for i in ppsStartIndex+4..<ppsStartIndex+34 {
            if frameData[i] == 0 && frameData[i+1] == 0 && frameData[i+2] == 0 && frameData[i+3] == 1 {
                frameStartIndex = i
                ppsSize = i - spsSize - 8 // Does not include the size of the header. Subtract 8 to account for both the SPS and PPS headers
                pps = Array(frameData[ppsStartIndex+4..<i])

                // Set naluType to the nested packet's NALU type
                naluType = frameData[i+4] & 0x1F
                break
            }
        }
        // If nested frame was found, fallthrough
        if frameStartIndex != 0 { fallthrough }
    // IDR frame
    case 5:
        print("===== NALU type IDR frame");

        // Replace start code with size
        let adjustedSize = size - UInt32(ppsSize) - UInt32(spsSize) - 8
        var blockSize = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(adjustedSize)
        memcpy(&frameData[frameStartIndex], &blockSize, 4)

        if createFormatDescription() {
            frame = decodeFrameData(Array(frameData[frameStartIndex...]))
        }
    // B/P frame
    default:
        print("===== NALU type B/P frame");

        // Replace start code with size
        var blockSize = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(size)
        memcpy(&frameData[frameStartIndex], &blockSize, 4)

        frame = decodeFrameData(Array(frameData[frameStartIndex...]))
        break;
    }

    return frame != nil ? frame : nil
}
```

And this is where the actual decoding happens:

```
private func decodeFrameData(_ frameData: FrameData) -> CMSampleBuffer? {
    let bufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: frameData)
    let size = frameData.count

    var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?
    var status = CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    bufferPointer,
                                                    size,
                                                    kCFAllocatorNull,
                                                    nil, 0, frameData.count,
                                                    0, &blockBuffer)

    if status != kCMBlockBufferNoErr { return nil }

    var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?
    let sampleSizeArray = [size]

    status = CMSampleBufferCreateReady(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       blockBuffer,
                                       formatDesc,
                                       1, 0, &sampleTimingInfo,
                                       1, sampleSizeArray,
                                       &sampleBuffer)

    if let buffer = sampleBuffer, status == kCMBlockBufferNoErr {
        let attachments: CFArray? = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(buffer, true)

        if let attachmentArray = attachments {
            let dic = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachmentArray, 0), to: CFMutableDictionary.self)

            let key = Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately).toOpaque()
            let val = Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCFBooleanTrue).toOpaque()
            CFDictionarySetValue(dic,
                                 key,
                                 val)
        }

        print("===== Successfully created sample buffer")
        return buffer
    }

    return nil
}
```

Other things to note:

- The formatDescription contains the correct information (mediaType = "vide", mediaSubType = "avc1", dimensions = "640x480")
- The bitstream I'm decoding *always* groups the SPS, PPS, and IDR frames together and sends them as one big packet every 20 or so frames. Every other time, an individual B/P frame is sent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That code was pretty ugly so I decided to touch it up a little bit. Turned out that did the trick. Something must have been wrong in there.

Anyways, here's a working version. It sends the decoded & decompressed frame to its delegate. Ideally, whoever calls *interpretRawFrameData* would be returned a displayable frame, and I'll work on that, but in the meantime this works too.

https://github.com/philipshen/H264Decoder